# What's the use of parameters.yml file in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I used to write my configs for Symfony project like this in config.yml file:

```
my_bundle:
    internal_identifier: %test%
    key: %someparam%
    endpoint: %nobil_endpoint%
```

and used parameters.yml (which was ignored by git) for allowing other developers to have different values.

Bu I think using this:

```
my_bundle:
    internal_identifier: my-identifier
    key: 12345
    endpoint: www.endpoint.com
```

still allows developers to have different values because they can use config_dev.yml which is also ignored by Git.

So my question is this: what's the purpose of parameters.yml file if config_dev.yml can be used for the same thing?

Comment: Because in every other project config_dev.yml is not ignored. parameters.yml is, as the name suggests, a storage of configurable parameters, whereas config_dev.yml is configuration file for dev environment. For the most part, it should be static from dev to dev and without it, app_dev.php will crash.

Comment: Thanks, I tought config_dev.yml should be ignored. Thanks for the info, now it makes sense to have a parameters.yml file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think two things are being asked here:

1. Why is parameters.yml ignored be the default Symfony .gitignore file?
2. Why use parameters.yml instead of config_dev.yml?

Per the first question, parameters.yml is ignored by default because this file is meant to hold settings which are per-installation. For instance different developers might need different database settings. If parameters.yml wasn't ignored, your "personal" settings would be copied to every developer.

[As of Symfony 2.3 you should put the needed parameters, along with default values, in a file called **parameters.yml.dist**.](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-interactive-management-of-the-parameters-yml-file) Then, when you run composer install a composer script will check for this file and create/update your local parameters.yml file, prompting you for each setting which gives you the opportunity to change the settings to be relevant to the given install.

Per the second issue, parameters are considered different than config settings. Parameters are settings which will change install to install, whereas config settings will stay the same for all installs of a particular app ([although they may be different from dev to production environments](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html).)

Answer (score 2):

first, what is ignored by git is up to you, there is a .gitignore file in your repo-root

my advice to use different parameters would be:

you have different parameter.yml´s  like :

```
parameters.yml.dev.one
parameters.yml.dev.two
parameters.yml.dev.three
```

and for example you are developer one then you make a symbolic link to "your" parameters.yml.dev.one like :

```
cd app/config; ln -s parameters.yml.dev.one parameters.yml
```

so now there is a parameters.yml on your machine that points on your parameters

developer two would make a symbolic link to his parameters and so on

if you are not clear about the difference between parameters and config, please check symfony book

you can do the same with your stages when you need for example another database-connection on prelive or live or whatever by using symbolic links

the advantage of this is that every developer has the parameters of every stage and developer on his machine

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Being ignored by Git is the most useful, but it also prompts you for missing values when doing `composer install`.

If you want to have common parameters that are not ignored, you can create a `parameters_common.yml` and source it in `config.yml` (or add them directly in config.yml).

For an advanced use of config/parameters files, I suggest you check https://github.com/wemakecustom/DirectoryLoaderBundle

Answer (score 0):

Because where you are in production environment, symfony needs to work in PRODuction environment and not in DEV.

Why you removed config_dev.yml from repository?

Comment: But you can use config_prod.yml for that. I ignored it because sometimes we work with different values.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This project had a config_prod.yml file and also a config.yml. But still, if you were in production you use config.yml and if you're on dev you use config_dev.yml. I still don't see the point of the parameters.yml.

Comment: I just checked and also the current version of Symfony comes with a config_prod.yml file.

Comment: When you install your sf app, you can configure that installation with parameter and keep config_dev the same for each developer.